# `export const config` Please change `runtime` property to segment export config

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am basically trying to create upload api route in my application.

```
/admin/upload
```

and when I try to `console.log(req.file)`, I keeping I get undefined.

It seems that this:

```
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
}
```

Is not supported while using app router, I can't figure any other ways.

```
import { createEdgeRouter } from "next-connect";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import multer from "multer";

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
}

const router = createEdgeRouter();

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './public/uploads',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname),
    }),
});

const file = upload.single('file');
router
    .use(file)
    .post((req) => {
        // console.log(req.pageType);
        console.log(req.pageType);
        return NextResponse.json({ 'message': 'Hi mom' })
    });

export async function POST(req, ctx) {
    return NextResponse.json("Hi")
}
```

Here is my backend code.

When I checked docs at the [page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) mentioned, I couldn't find anything helpful.
Any idea how to fix this?

Please note I am using app router not pages router.

Comment: I found many answers online but all related to pages router not app router.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49025) can help. I needed to use it in my Stripe webhook endpoint, and when I was passing the endpoint from `pages/` to `/app`, I ran into the same error message.

I found that GitHub issue, and it provides more helpful information than the link in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the project root (or `/src` if you're using `/src` folder)